# how to use multiple custom components in framework in ag-grid-angular?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2, ag-grid-angular

I have created two custom components, i.e custom tooltip component and custom datepicker component. when im trying to declare in framework it is not working.
Its taking only datepicker custom component not tooltip component. If datepicker component is removed then its taking tooltip component Its considering only one custom component in frameworkComponent.
Please find the below code:

CustomTooltip :

```
import {Component, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';
import {ITooltipAngularComp} from "ag-grid-angular";

@Component({
    selector: 'tooltip-component',
    template: `
        <div class="custom-tooltip" [style.background-color]="data.color">
            <p>{{tooltipData}}</p>
        </div>`,


    styles: [
        `
            :host {
                position: absolute;
                width: 250px;
                height: 60px;
                border: 1px solid cornflowerblue;
                overflow: hidden;
                pointer-events: none;
                transition: opacity 1s;
            }

            :host.ag-tooltip-hiding {
                opacity: 0;
            }

            .custom-tooltip p {
                margin: 5px;
                white-space: nowrap;
            }
        `
    ],
    styleUrls: ['./custom-tooltip.component.scss']
})
export class CustomTooltip implements ITooltipAngularComp {

     params: any;
     data: any;
    tooltipData: any;

    agInit(params): void {
        console.log("params",params.value);
        this.params = params;
        this.tooltipData=params.value;
        this.data = params.api.getRowNode(params.rowIndex).data;
        this.data.color = this.params.color || 'white';
    }
}
```

CustomDateComponent:

```
import {Component, ElementRef, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import flatpickr from 'flatpickr'

@Component({
    selector: 'app-loading-overlay',
    template: `
        <div #flatpickrEl class="ag-input-text-wrapper custom-date-filter fa">
            <input type='text' data-input />
            <a class='input-button' title='clear' data-clear>
                <i class='fa fa-times'></i>
            </a>&nbsp;
            <a class="input-button" title="toggle" data-toggle>
            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
            </a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
        </div>
    `,
    styles: [
        `
    .custom-date-filter a {
    position: relative;
    right: 34px;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .custom-date-filter:after {
    content: '\f073';
    display: block;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
    position: relative;
    right: 25px;
    pointer-events: none;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
  }
    `
    ]
})
export class CustomDateComponent {
    @ViewChild("flatpickrEl", {read: ElementRef}) flatpickrEl: ElementRef;
    private date: Date;
    private params: any;
    private picker: any;

    agInit(params: any): void {
        this.params = params;
    }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        // outputs `I am span`
        this.picker = flatpickr(this.flatpickrEl.nativeElement, {
            onChange: this.onDateChanged.bind(this),
            wrap: true
        });

        this.picker.calendarContainer.classList.add('ag-custom-component-popup');
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        console.log(`Destroying DateComponent`);
    }

    onDateChanged(selectedDates) {
        this.date = selectedDates[0] || null;
        this.params.onDateChanged();
    }

    getDate(): Date {
        return this.date;
    }

    setDate(date: Date): void {
       this.date = date || null;
       this.picker.setDate(date);
    }
}
```

Im trying to use both custom component in one grid i.e:

```
 this.columnDefs = [
      {
        headerName: 'Request Number', field: 'request_no', sortable: true, filter: 'agNumberColumnFilter'
      },
      {
        headerName: 'Request Date', field: 'created_at', sortable: true, width: 300,
        filter: "agDateColumnFilter",
        filterParams: {
          comparator: function (filterLocalDateAtMidnight, cellValue) {
            var dateAsString = cellValue;
            var dateParts = dateAsString.split("/");
            var cellDate = new Date(Number(dateParts[2]), Number(dateParts[1]) - 1, Number(dateParts[0]));
            if (filterLocalDateAtMidnight.getTime() === cellDate.getTime()) {
              return 0;
            }
            if (cellDate < filterLocalDateAtMidnight) {
              return -1;
            }
            if (cellDate > filterLocalDateAtMidnight) {
              return 1;
            }
          }
        }
      },
      { headerName: 'Requested By', field: 'user_name', sortable: true, filter: 'agTextColumnFilter', tooltipField: 'user_name' },
      {
        headerName: 'Client', field: 'borrower_name', sortable: true, filter: 'agTextColumnFilter',
        tooltipField: 'borrower_name', tooltipComponentParams: { color: "#ececec" }, width: 200
      },
      {
        headerName: 'Debtor', field: 'customer_name', sortable: true, filter: 'agTextColumnFilter',
        cellStyle: { color: 'blue', cursor: 'pointer' }, tooltipField: 'customer_name', width: 200
      },
      {
        headerName: 'Current Limit', field: 'current_limit', sortable: true, filter: 'agNumberColumnFilter',
        cellStyle: { textAlign: 'right' },
        cellRenderer: this.CurrencyCellRenderer
      },
      {
        headerName: 'Requested Limit', field: 'requested_limit', sortable: true, filter: 'agNumberColumnFilter',
        cellStyle: { textAlign: 'right' },
        cellRenderer: this.CurrencyCellRenderer
      },
      {
        headerName: 'Approved Limit', field: 'approved_limit', sortable: true, filter: 'agNumberColumnFilter',
        cellStyle: { textAlign: 'right' },
        cellRenderer: this.CurrencyCellRenderer
      },
      { headerName: 'Status', field: 'status', sortable: true, filter: 'agTextColumnFilter', width: 120, },
      { headerName: 'Comment', field: 'comment', sortable: true, filter: 'agTextColumnFilter', tooltipField: 'comment', width: 200 },
      {
        headerName: "",
        suppressMenu: true,
        suppressSorting: false,
        cellClass: 'action-class',
        width: 120,
        template:
          `<i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true" data-action-type="view" pTooltip="Edit Queue" tooltipPosition="top"></i> 
          &nbsp; <i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true" data-action-type="history"  pTooltip="View Comment History" tooltipPosition="top"></i>`
      }
    ];
    this.defaultColDef = {
      enableValue: true,
      sortable: true,
      tooltipComponent: "customTooltip",
      resizable: true
    };
    this.frameworkComponents = { 
       customTooltip: CustomTooltip,
       agDateInput: CustomDateComponent };
```

Comment: You can do it, but in your last code you're  only using the customTooltip  and not the agDateInput?
Also can you provide  a stackblitz example  with the code provided

Comment: https://next.plnkr.co/edit/0ZyYiWN5PSAITfSijDqf?p=preview&preview plunker link

Answer (score 0):

Seems it's a custom `tooltip` issue (somewhere inside ag-grid), will try to inform the team and describe the bug.

In your case, you can specify your component (`CustomDateComponent`) directly via `cellEditorFramework` rather than `cellEditor`, without internal declaration in `frameworkComponents` block.

```
{
    headerName: "Date",
    field: "date",
    width: 190,
    editable:true,
    cellEditorFramework:CustomDateComponent
}
```

*Just for info: your `CustomDateComponent` not yet ready to be used as [`cellEditor`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editor/)*